# how to decide the best way to communicate between components in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, components

How to decide which way I should choose when facing interactions between multiple components?

I read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html for all of those methods we currently have, but under what kinds of circumstance should we decide to use the particular one of them?

Could someone give some examples?

**Edit:
I notice if I have a service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { mA, mB } from '../Model/app.Model';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    private source = new Subject<mA>(); //copied from the tutorial in Angluar 2 website
    sourceStream$ = this.source.asObservable(); //make it ovbservable for other components to subscrib to it

    public serviceFunc(ma: mA) {
        this.source.next(ma);
    }
}
```

And a ParentCMP

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { mA , mB} from './Model/app.Model';
import { SharedService } from './Service/app.SharedService';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/some/url'
    , providers: [SharedService]
})

export class ParentCMP {
    someVarIWantToChange: mA;

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
      sharedService.sourceStream$.subscribe(ma => { this.someVarIWantToChange = ma;
    });
    }
}
```

And a ChildCMP_Speaker

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { mA, mB } from './Model/app.Model';
import { SharedService } from './Service/app.SharedService'; //reference the service

@Component({
    selector: 'child-app'
    , templateUrl: '/some/url'
    , providers: [SharedService]
})


export class ChildCMP {
    someValue: mA; //local copy of the mA value

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {

    }

    onClick(value: mA) {
        this.someValue = value;
        this.sharedService.serviceFunc(this.someValue);
    }
}
```

I call the onClick function on the ChildCMP template page, successfully get the value : mA, and the line which calling the service got executed. BUT, the **someVarIWantToChange** does not change at all. Did I do something wrong?

and by doing this, what is the difference with using a emit, and subscribe to the emit? Should I use .next() or .emit()? And why?

Comment: That's because you have the `SharedService` in `providers: [...]` of `ChildCMP`. Angular DI maintains an instance per provider. In your case `ParentCMP` and `ChildCMP` have 2 different instances of `SharedService`. Remove it from the child component and DI looks upwards towards the root component for providers and will find the one in `ParentCMP` which will lead to both using the same instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a direct parent-child relation (child is in the template of the parent) use binding

Otherwise use a shared service.

If values of a shared service can change, use an observable so the components and services interested in this status don't have to poll and instead can subscribe to changes to get notified.

**update**

That's because you have the SharedService in providers: [...] of ChildCMP. Angular DI maintains an instance per provider. In your case ParentCMP and ChildCMP have 2 different instances of SharedService. Remove it from the child component and DI looks upwards towards the root component for providers and will find the one in ParentCMP which will lead to both using the same instance.

Comment: Man you are a GOD. Thank you!

Comment: Not even close, just a lot of experience spotting issues in Angular2 code ;-)

Comment: Yes you are spot on, using Inputs/Outputs with components that have no relatiion can get really confusing and messy!!!